# ExpandableListView Android how to control state of checkbox of child and change checkbox true in parent

Tags: java, android

I've tried to find any tutorial from go*gle and you*ube, but I'm still not yet find out what I need.
I have create a layout like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1N3g.jpg)

when i checked R or H on Child was true in parent change to cross and red background like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDsxn.jpg)

any idea or reference to let me read the flow of code please?
thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You must use a selector in to achieve what you are trying. Create a xml drawable file with follows -

**checkbox_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_checkbox_background" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_checkbox_background" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

Then use this selector as background on your checkbox as follows -

```
<CheckBox
    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

Then according to the state of checkbox, `state_checked="true` or `state_checked="false` background of the checkbox will change.

As an example you can create `selected_checkbox_background.xml` as follows -

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#E44747"/>
    <corners radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Edit 1**

To make changes in the checkbox state programmatically, use listener and setChecked() method something as follows -

```
childCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if(isChecked){
            parentCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Its not very clear for me to understand how you are grouping different checkbox, but I am providing following code according to my understanding -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private CheckBox checkCheckbox1, crossCheckbox1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkCheckbox1 = findViewById(R.id.check_checkbox1);
        crossCheckbox1 = findViewById(R.id.cross_checkbox1);
        CheckBox rCheckbox1 = findViewById(R.id.r_checkbox1);
        CheckBox hCheckbox2 = findViewById(R.id.h_checkbox1);
        
        // you can apply listener on each checkbox as follows
        rCheckbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked)
                    enableCrossCheckbox(checkCheckbox1, crossCheckbox1);
                else 
                    disableCrossCheckbox(checkCheckbox1, crossCheckbox1);
            }
        });

        //or you can make Class implement CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener and use onCheckedChanged() method
        rCheckbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        hCheckbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    private void enableCrossCheckbox(CheckBox checkBox, CheckBox crossBox){
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
        crossBox.setChecked(true);
    }

    private void disableCrossCheckbox(CheckBox checkBox, CheckBox crossBox){
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        crossBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    //on making class implementing CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.r_checkbox1:
                if(isChecked)
                    enableCrossCheckbox(checkCheckbox1, crossCheckbox1);
                else
                    disableCrossCheckbox(checkCheckbox1, crossCheckbox1);
                break;
            //....................... and so on
        }
    }
}
```

Happy Coding !

Comment: how to get position checkbox on groupview and change from check to cross  when checkbox on child was clicked ?

Comment: @Adinugraha I edited the answer, take a look, if that's not what you are looking for then you need to provide your layout xml code.